# Tricks to Help Speed Up Loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a loop going through a full sheet of form responses. I send out emails to each individual if they have not been emailed yet. As you can imagine this sheet can get rather large and will continue to grow.

So what I do currently is I grab the full set of data into an array and then loop through it. If the person has a timestamp for email sent then I skip to the next person. Even looping through an array is taking a long time. With ~7K rows I quit after 15 min.

The obvious solution... one that worked for me until now was to find the next available row that had not received an email yet and start from there.

```
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var requestsSht = tss.getSheetByName('Requests');

  //Grab full sheet data in one call
  var requestsLR = requestsSht.getLastRow(); 
  var requestsLC = requestsSht.getLastColumn();
  var requestShtArr = requestsSht.getRange(1,1,requestsLR,requestsLC).getValues();

  //Find the next row that has not received an email yet. (First row with blank cell for timestamp)  
  var emailDateCN = 7; //column number where timestamps are placed after they are emailed.
  var timeStampsArr = requestsSht.getRange(1,emailDateCN,requestsLR,1).getValues(); //get all data in one call
  var nextRowReadyForEmail = 0;
  while (timeStampsArr[nextRowReadyForEmail] && timeStampsArr[nextRowReadyForEmail][0] != "" ) {
    nextRowReadyForEmail++;
  }
  nextRowReadyForEmail = nextRowReadyForEmail+1
  
  //Start looping through rows   
  for (var i = nextRowReadyForEmail; i <= requestShtArr.length; i++) {
    //do what I need to do here
  }
```

While that worked given the circumstances before, I now will have blank timestamp cells throughout the column... no longer all grouped together at the end. I need to preserve the position as is so sorting is not an option.

How would you approach this?

Additional Info based on Community Questions:

- I have to be able to refer to that row within my code to place a time stamp on the respective row after emailing. I also pull info from that row (different column to place in the body of the email).
- Sample Sheet. I put a sample of the data I have. Of course this is a small sample. Actual sheet is 7K lines long now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wcCPm5VMIjSwkaVe2G23MBTj8LtbN008wLQZrdHwj08/edit#gid=2100307022

You notice on the sample sheet that column G has a timestamp if they have received an email already. Because the ones without timestamps are not all grouped I have to loop through each row in the array and that takes a long time. I also need to, as mentioned before, preserve the order of these rows.

Comment: I added a sample sheet to my original post. Take a look at that and see if you need more details. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing a sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I could confirm "Build Sample Here" sheet. Is this the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation using your sample input situation? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: I just need to email those that do not have timestamps for Email Send Date column. They will receive an email that has some data and it will include their first name in the body of the message. Then after I email I put a time stamp in that column.

I already have all of that sorted out. I just need to speed up looping. I need to figure out how to speed it up with so many rows. There may be 25 emails that need to be sent but it loops through the whole array and it takes way too long.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your output situation, only column "G" is updated by adding the date object. Is my understanding correct? And about `I just need to speed up looping. I need to figure out how to speed it up with so many rows. There may be 25 emails that need to be sent`, in your actual situation, only 25 emails are required to be sent even when there are a lot of rows. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. 25 is an example to show that there will be many more that have already been emailed versus those that need to be emailed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I just need to email those that do not have timestamps for Email Send Date column. They will receive an email that has some data and it will include their first name in the body of the message. Then after I email I put a time stamp in that column. I already have all of that sorted out. I just need to speed up looping. I need to figure out how to speed it up with so many rows. There may be 25 emails that need to be sent but it loops through the whole array and it takes way too long.

> Yes, that is correct. 25 is an example to show that there will be many more that have already been emailed versus those that need to be emailed.

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a Spreadsheet including a lot of rows.
- You want to send emails by checking column "G" of the Spreadsheet. When column "G" is empty, you want to send an email using the row value.
- The number of emails is about 25 emails.
- You want to set the date object to column "G" when the email is sent.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

Unfortunately, I do not know your script for sending the email. So, in this sample script, the script for sending emails is not included. Please use your script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and set your sheet name. And, please set your script for sending emails.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Build Sample Here"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const ranges = sheet.getRange("A2:H" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, row, i) => {
    if (!row[6]) {

      // Please set your script for sending emails using the row value of "row", here.

      ar.push(`G${i + 2}`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(new Date());
}
```

- When this script is run, the column "G" is checked whether the cell value is empty. When the cell value is empty, you can use the row value. And, the date object is put into column "G".

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))

Comment: In your sample how would I store a value to a variable. Let's say I want the name of the person and that is in column C. ```var firstName = ??? ```. Is it ```sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue()```

Comment: I see. ```var firstName = row[2]```

Comment: A couple more questions. I'm not familiar with this method. Is there a way to skip to the next iteration like we do in a for loop with ```continue;``` or would we just add another condition to the ```if``` statement? Also, I will be setting the date value within the email script so I don't need ```ar```. When I do ```reduce((row, i)``` I get an error.

Comment: I found this solution to best suit my needs. I will select it as the answer. If you can please answer the question I asked above I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @DanCue About your 2nd question of `In your sample how would I store a value to a variable. Let's say I want the name of the person and that is in column C. var firstName = ??? . Is it sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue()`, in my sample script, your `I see. var firstName = row[2]` is correct. `row[2]` is value of column "C".

Comment: @DanCue About your 3ed question of `A couple more questions. I'm not familiar with this method. Is there a way to skip to the next iteration like we do in a for loop with continue; or would we just add another condition to the if statement? Also, I will be setting the date value within the email script so I don't need ar. When I do reduce((row, i) I get an error.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 3rd question. Can I ask you about the details of your 3rd question?

Comment: When using a for loop I can skip an iteration by using ```continue;```. Can I skip an iteration in your script above?

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. About `When using a for loop I can skip an iteration by using continue;. Can I skip an iteration in your script above?`, in this case, the if statement is used. For example, you can skip a loop by `if (some condition) return;` or `if (some condition) { some tasks }`. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Your example has some undefined variables.  It definitely does not meet the requirements for minimum reproducible example.  So here's my best guess.

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => !r[emailDateCN - 1]).filter(e => e);//only keeping the items with emailDateCN falsy
  vs.forEach(r => {
    //send email to all of these
  }) 
}
```

But I also would have considered building my own list via onformSubmit trigger that is separate from the linked sheet and only kept the ones that haven't been emailed yet and just delete the ones that have as I go thus keeping the list a lot smaller.  You can always return to the original linked list if you want to keep a permanent record but at some  point old data is just a big waste of time.

Perhaps this might work:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let o = vs.map((r, i) => { r.push(i + 1) })
  o.filter(r => !r[emailDateCN - 1]).filter(e => e);//only keeping the items with emailDateCN falsy
  o.forEach(r => {
    //row is r[r.length - 1]
  })
}
```

Comment: Help me out here. What is ```[mcve]```? I added emailDateCN and requestsSht defined variables. Was that all I was missing?

Comment: Let me add some more info though... I have to send each email individually. I have to add a timestamp when i'm done sending the email to each. Can I still do this after you've reduced the array to those filtered values?

Comment: Please add your additional information to your question so that everyone has an opportunity to read the complete question without having to read through all of the comments

Comment: I did immediately after I wrote that comment to you.

Comment: In your case probably not.  But in my world first of all I never do anything with linked sheets...I just let them save the data and I would create a separate of list of items that need to be emailed and delete them as I go so that I don't end up with a huge list of work that's already done.  The reality is the email delivery is not guaranteed so it's always possible that someone wont get an email and if they don't and complain I still have whatever raw data is in the linked sheet.

Comment: I was thinking.. this may work if I had a helper column that had the row numbers on it. If I grabbed the contents of the sheet into an array, filtered to only keep items with emailDateCN = to false, then I could use the column with row numbers on it to refer to the rows I need. Does that sound like it would work or are there better ways?

Comment: I have done that.  It should work.

Comment: Understood. I was just looking to see if I'm on the right path with my thinking. With your code I would need a helper column, right?

Comment: I just pushed the row onto the end

Comment: Maybe I'm just not understanding. In my loop before I would use i for the row. what am I using now? ```r``` or ```r[r.length-1]```?

Comment: o is an array of rows so r is a row